# Jewish Life vs. Opinion-based

Tags: discussion, policy, close-reasons

This is not to rehash the [Jewish life parameters](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/262/9682). Go take that over there.

My question is where we draw the line between that and off-topic as opinion based. Jewish life questions seem to be of the form "Judaism causes problem X. Any tips on how to solve that?"

For instance: [Exercises to prevent eyes tiring](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8548/exercises-to-prevent-eyes-tiring)

[Advice for Lighting in a Sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19096/9682)

[How can I make a long summer shabbat a delight?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7625/9682)

[How do you deal with huge numbers of calls from tzedaka organizations?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4/))

These two actually did get closed as opinion-based:

[What bar/bat mitzva present did you actually want/like/use?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1741/9682)

[What would you really, actually like to receive (give?) for Mishloach Manot on Purim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/301/9682)

Comment: Granted that [some of them](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5958/9682) do not fall under the range of this question.

Comment: In brief: [Experience and opinion are not the same thing.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: How is this not rehashing Jewish life parameters? Which answer there are you even asking according to? There is no top voted one.

Comment: @mevaqesh (You really do like arguing with me on that point, don't you?) I'm not asking what is considered on-topic regarding Jewish life. I'm asking how Jewish life is on-topic, regardless of how it's defined, when subjective questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From our (and every Stack Exchange site's) [FAQ page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on "What types of questions should I avoid asking?":

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”

...

> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be *constructive*.** What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun
>
> For more detail, read about [our guidelines for great subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and blog post about [how real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

I encourage you to read the full "Good Subjective, Bad Subjective" blog post linked above. The list of qualities of "constructive subjective questions" above is a summary of that post's guidelines for "great subjective questions." Note that this is not the same thing as hard rules for acceptable subjective questions, which that post says are difficult to draw.

In general, I think it's wise, with respect to any question that has subjective aspects, to apply the overall advice in the blog post:

> Apply the six subjective question guidelines and see how it scores. If the score is low, close it. If the score is high, vote it up.

More particularly, this meta question concerns mainly questions that fall into two main categories: [product-recommendation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-recommendation) and [how-to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to).

With respect to product recommendations, we've written what has emerged as a primary consideration into the [product-recommendation tag wiki](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/product-recommendation/info):

> Questions in this tag should give explicit, specific guidelines describing the sought after qualities in the product. "A **really good** Fizzboop" is *not* sufficiently explicit and should be closed as primarily opinion based.

I'd say that a similar standard ought to apply to [how-to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to) questions: It should be clear from the question what criteria would make one answer better than another. In many cases, simply stating a particular problem to solve clearly is probably sufficient, since the implied overall criterion is how well answers solve that problem.