# Site scope in Tour seems to disagree with scope defined in the Help Center

Tags: discussion, support, scope, help-center

The site tour says it is *on-topic* to ask about:

> - general knowledge ... as it relates directly to Jewish life and learning

While the Help Center article on site scope says it is *off-topic* to ask

> questions unrelated to Judaism, even if they are about...
>
> - Jews, Jewish history, and Israel

These two characterizations are not disjoint.

For example, a question on an aspect of the history of Jewish communities does "relate to Jewish life", but could be said not to be "related to Judaism".

Please try to clarify and unify both statements to agree with the current (or the desired) moderation policy.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/262/759

Comment: @DoubleAA: Based on that link, it appears it is the _Tour_ scope description that needs tweaking.

Comment: "Needs" is a bit of an overstatement IMO. Perhaps it could be somewhat clearer but reading the whole thing in context doesn't leave much ambiguity. An extreme read of the phrase "Jewish life" even includes questions about medical treatment for elderly Jews! If someone wants to propose a better wording though they can certainly do so, perhaps in an answer here.